# How to can check the string exists in sentence or not

Tags: php

how i can check a value in PHP string that it's exists or not
while when is use **strpos()** function then i face a problem when i check in a string 
suppose i have a string **I m a Programmer**
then if i check Pro then **strpos** show its index value

```
<?php
$string="I m Programmer";
$found="Prog";
echo strpos($string,$found);
?>
```

**strpos()** show Porg index value while i want if **Prog** word exists in string then show index value if its not then should be show nothing because i want *match* **Programmer** work fully not **Prog**

Comment: So basically you want to check full word? Like "Programmer" and not "Prog"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do by using `pre_match()` function, due to `i` it'll ignore case sensitive. for more detail you can read the `pre_match` documents here. [pre_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php
// for insensitive string
function insensitive($val,$str){
    if(preg_match("/\b$val\b/i",$str) ){
      return 1;
    }else{
      return 0;
    }
}
// for case sensitive string
function sensitive($val,$str){
    if(preg_match("/\b$val\b/",$str) ){
      return 1;
    }else{
      return 0;
    }
}
$string = 'I m programmer'; 
$found="Programmer"; 

// call function like this to get result
echo insensitive($found,$string);
echo sensitive($found,$string);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
$string = 'I m Programmer'; //  "I m Programmer." - will work too
$found="programmer"; // lower case
echo preg_match("/\b$found\b/i",$string) ? 'Matched' : 'No Match';
```

`i` modifier for insensitive. Case insensitive match

[preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php
$string = 'I m Programmer';
$found="Prog";
if ( preg_match("~\b$found\b~",$string) ){
    echo "Matched";
}else{
   echo "No Match";
}
?>
```

Not case sensitive :

```
if ( preg_match("~\b".strtolower($found)."\b~",strtolower($string)) ){
    echo "Matched";
}else{
   echo "No Match";
}
```

Comment: its case sensitive i don't want this

Comment: fixed @MuGhalProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

You also can use strpos, just check the char after the searched if is in a~z.

```
$str = strtolower($str);
$search = strtolower($search);
$is_in = (false !== ($pos = strpos($str,$search))) && !in_array($str[$pos + strlen($search)],['a','b','c',...'z']);
```